# No route matches (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a simple link to another page in my rails app but it doesnt seem to work.Even though I have configured a route for my posts index page it gives me the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"posts", :lat=>5, :controller=>"coordinates"}
```

Here's my Directory structure:

[image]

My **routes.rb** file

```
HighwayPolice::Application.routes.draw do

resources:posts
resources:coords
resources:coordinates
get 'posts', to: 'posts#index'  
end
```

**../app/views/coordinates/index.html.erb**

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCThq7kV6r4-cILKpujZek5e-uZGbGdjkU&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
     function initialize()
     {console.log("click");
    var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    zoom: 8
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
console.log(event.latLng.k);
});
var test = 3;
$('#Test').val(test);
console.log(test);
var lat = 3
        var lon = 34
        var parsed_data = {location: {lat: lat, lon: lon}}

}

</script>


<h1>Coordinates#index</h1>
<body onload = "initialize()">
<div id="map-canvas" style = "width:500px; height:500px"></div>
<p>Find me in app/views/coordinates/index.html.erb</p>
<% @coordinates.each do |coordinate| %>
<p><%= coordinate.longitude %></p>
<p><%= coordinate.lattitude %></p>
<hr />
<% end %> 
<%= link_to('Save',{:action => 'post', :lat => 5}) %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
   end
```

Comment: Your coordinates controller has a posts method correct?

Comment: Also you don't indicate in your routes that you have a posts action in your coordinates controller. You can add one by doing. Resources :coordinates do member :posts end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current link is trying to post to the coordinates controller posts action.

If you want to post to the posts controller as specified in your routes controller try something like

```
link_to "Save", controller: :posts, action: :index, lat: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do a post request on the coordinates controller, you use `method: :post` instead of `:action => 'post'`

if you are trying to post data to action called 'post' in coordinates controller then you should add a matching a the top of the routes files, as `resources: coordinates` will only add CRUD operations (see section 2.5 in this link[http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html] for full list of methods) on the coordinates controller. so you should add `match 'coordinates/post' to 'coordinates#post', via: :post` to the top of the routes file.